# Syntax error while trying to execute declared query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to get an automated report sent out each month using `sp_send_dbmail`. I've gotten basic reports set up just fine in the past but for whatever reason I am unable to do so with my current report. I have two queries joined together with a Union statement. Alone, each query result can be emailed out just fine but with a union statement I get the following error:

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Because of this error I have been trouble shooting my query. My query runs just fine but when I assign it to a variable, it gives me a very generic error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29 Incorrect syntax near '='.

Does anyone have any idea about what I could change?

```
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(800) = N'
Select 
       STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMLNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMFNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMSTS
       ,STFMST.SMEMAL
       ,STFMST.SMUSRI
          ,''In Essentia, Not HRIS''
From 
       Essentia.dbo.STAFFMSTR 
       left outer join hris.dbo.hris on (HRIS.[Empl ID] = STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM)
       left outer join essentia.dbo.STFMST on stfstf = SMMNUM
WHERE 
       HRIS.[Empl ID] IS NULL 
       and SMMSTS = ''A''
       and SMMNUM not in (1,2,10001,99999,8447)
UNION
Select 
       STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMLNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMFNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMSTS
       ,STFMST.SMEMAL
       ,STFMST.SMUSRI
          ,''Active in Essentia, Termed in HRIS''
From 
       Essentia.dbo.STAFFMSTR 
       -- Line 29 -- left outer join hris.dbo.hris on (HRIS.[Empl ID] = STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM)
       left outer join essentia.dbo.STFMST on stfstf = SMMNUM 
WHERE 
       SMMSTS = ''A''
       and [EE Status] = ''T''
       and SMMNUM not in (1,2,10001,99999,8447)
       order by SMMNUM'


Exec (@querystring)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your variable first (changed size of the column from `800` to `MAX`):

```
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

Then initialize it (removed `N` string literal):

```
SET @QueryString = '
Select 
       STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMLNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMFNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMSTS
       ,STFMST.SMEMAL
       ,STFMST.SMUSRI
          ,''In Essentia, Not HRIS''
From 
       Essentia.dbo.STAFFMSTR 
       left outer join hris.dbo.hris on (HRIS.[Empl ID] = STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM)
       left outer join essentia.dbo.STFMST on stfstf = SMMNUM
WHERE 
       HRIS.[Empl ID] IS NULL 
       and SMMSTS = ''A''
       and SMMNUM not in (1,2,10001,99999,8447)
UNION
Select 
       STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMLNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMFNM
       ,STAFFMSTR.SMMSTS
       ,STFMST.SMEMAL
       ,STFMST.SMUSRI
          ,''Active in Essentia, Termed in HRIS''
From 
       Essentia.dbo.STAFFMSTR 
       -- Line 29 -- left outer join hris.dbo.hris on (HRIS.[Empl ID] = STAFFMSTR.SMMNUM)
       left outer join essentia.dbo.STFMST on stfstf = SMMNUM 
WHERE 
       SMMSTS = ''A''
       and [EE Status] = ''T''
       and SMMNUM not in (1,2,10001,99999,8447)
       order by SMMNUM';
```

Then execute it (changed `EXEC` to `EXECUTE`):

```
EXECUTE(@QueryString);
```

Comment: I guess it was just the length I set it to.. Changed it to MAX it worked just fine. How do I rep you?! Thanks for the help, I googled all day!

Comment: Here's how you can give a rep to someone by upvoting and/or accepting the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235